# Why is my share dialog empty? Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I'm trying to post to facebook, which works fine but none of my strings from my content variables are being added to the share dialog.

```
let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "<INSERT STRING HERE>")
content.contentTitle = "My Title Here"
content.contentDescription = "My description here!"
content.imageURL = NSURL(string: "<INSERT STRING HERE>")


let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
shareDialog.fromViewController = self
shareDialog.shareContent = content
shareDialog.delegate = self

if !shareDialog.canShow() {
    print("cannot show native share dialog")
}

shareDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook's policies don't allow you to pre-populate status messages and require all content to be user generated. Here is what I have done and I managed to get the URL in the Facebook popup:

```
let activityItems = ["My app text", "", "http://google.com"]

let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If I open Twitter for example I get "My app text" and the URL, for Facebook I only get the URL.

Comment: How do games post their score to facebook then? Or is that not allowed anymore. That is essentially what i wanted to do

Comment: Unfortunately not, you can read more about that here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill